# Windows program to show available updates for all programs on computer

Tags: gratis, windows-7, automation

I am looking for a program that shows me all the programs on my computer that have available updates. I would click a button, and they will all be updated automatically.

I want it to:

- be free
- have no dialog boxes, or confirmation boxes
- automatically install the updates (I don't want to have to manually download all the installers, then install them...)
- run on Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: http://lifehacker.com/5384140/five-best-software-update-tools

Comment: http://www.digitalcitizen.life/best-tools-check-software-updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Patch My PC Updater](https://patchmypc.net/download):

- free
- Windows 7 x64
- no dialog boxes/confirmation boxes: it automatically installs all updates at once without the need of human intervention.
- update third-party applications
- portable
- light (401 KB for the current version)
- support about 100 applications

[image]

[image: 7]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[NPackd](https://npackd.appspot.com/) is an open source package manager for windows, it is able to install/remove/upgrade programs unattended.

NPackdCL is the command line tool that comes with NPackd, you can for example run this from a script/scheduled task to upgrade all your software that is currently not up-to-date.

A list of the software packages manageable with Npackd is available at https://npackd.appspot.com/p

An alernative is [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/)

Comment: Other software package management systems:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_package_management_systems#Microsoft_Windows

Comment: So this will 1) check for updates 2) download *all* of them on command and 3) install *all* of them on command?

Comment: Wait for package lists to download, then click on "Installed, upgradeable" on the left pane to display packages with updates available, right click on them and run "Update". Or you could use the command line but I did not use it so far.

Comment: images are 404~

Answer (score 3):

[Avast](http://www.avast.com/) (free, Windows) has a module for that, but it doesn't support all applications:

[image]

[image]

Also, if you activate automatic update, it will update without asking you.

[image]

Comment: So I'd have to install the entire Avast Antivirus? Do you know of any lightweight solutions?

Comment: @ṧнʊß Sorry, I don't have anything off the top of my head.

Comment: OK, I'll wait for other people to suggest some