# Is there a software to manage updating the system?

Tags: windows

I want to check updates for software, drivers, windows itself, ... 
Is there a software to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows program to show available updates for all programs on computer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10041/windows-program-to-show-available-updates-for-all-programs-on-computer)

Comment: I would avoid automatic updates to drivers like the plague. It's a great way to brick your computer is one of them is broken. Windows updates are quite similar lately. Be wary of those!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with [SUMo](https://www.kcsoftwares.com/?sumo) you can keeps your PC up-to-date & safe by using the most recent version of the software.

Features:

- Automatic detection of installed software
- Detects required updates / patchs for your software
- Detects required drivers update (requires DUMo)
- Filter / authorize Beta versions (user setting)
- Automatic self-update (PRO only)
- Direct access to software developer's web site (PRO only)
- Ignore list : only tracks software YOU want to track
- More compatibility and less false positive than others Update Monitors (according to users feedback ;-)
- Internationalization support.

And the equivalent for drivers is [DUMo](https://www.kcsoftwares.com/?dumo).

Comment: I have used and can second both of these (although I long ago stopped using driver updaters, as it can occasionally lead to trouble). Upvoted